Java REST API Project - How to avoid entering the password in application.properties?
spring.application.name=Facilities
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://139.15.60.69:3306/project1
spring.datasource.username:user1
spring.datasource.password:XXXXXX
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port:8083
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

In application.properties, can the programmer avoid entering the password in this file.  While pushing to GitHub, the programmer will get a warning, if password is present.   What are the other approaches

using environment variables ?
using GitSecrets ?
Kindly guide in detail


We often forget to remove the password before GitPush. This is a concern
While creating a JAR file to run on cloud, password is mandatory here. Can we avoid this?


Springboot provides multiple ways to configure your application. Check the official documentation for an exhaustive list of possibilities (with even more when it comes to secrets).
The packaged application.properties is actually one of the less important sources of configuration. So you have quite a few options.
For deployment, it's impossible to answer without details, but environment variables are frequently used. It is even the way to go in the world of containerization.
As for each individual developer, set a workflow where no password (or any local custom configuration actually) should be put in any committed files to avoid mistakes. After that most IDE allow you to pass environment variables, JVM args, or program args when testing your application, all of which spring boot will map to your properties.
Beware that any committed password on git remains in the history as long as the commit exists.

There are a lot of ways to externalize configurations]. I like to use optional to import sensitive data, for example:
application.properties in the classpath:
spring.application.name=Facilities
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://139.15.60.69:3306/project1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port:8083
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.config.import: optional:file:./individual.properties

The individual.properties for each developer in the working directory, which must not commited:
spring.datasource.username:user1
spring.datasource.password:XXXXXX

Don't forget to include the individual.properties in your .gitignore file to avoid accidently commits!
Another benefit is that each developer could overwite or extend the default properties for its special needs!
